How to declare a fixed length string type within a record in C#?
I'm trying to create a record type in C# with some fields as fixed length strings.
I just want to use this record for further reading of a predefined file format.
I tried this:
  public record Person (int  age, fixed char  birthdate[8]);

However, I'm getting the following error
Array size cannot be specified in a variable declaration (try initializing with a 'new' expression)CS0270
I'm using the  Visual Studio Code Version: 1.88.1 (Universal).
Can you help me?
Thanks in advance,
Mario

There is no such thing as a fixed-length string in C#, instead you need to validate the input as it comes in.

Also, your value here, birthdate should not be a string, it should be a DateTime

First of all, the best path to folllow is use of Datetime as the comments said, but if you can't, you could throw an Exception on the record constructor:
public record Person
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Birthdate { get; set; }

    public Person(int age, string birthdate)
    {
        if (birthdate.Length != 8)
            throw new ArgumentException("Birthdate must be exactly 8 characters long.");

        Age = age;
        Birthdate = birthdate;
    }
}

With this, the first example will pass, but the second will throw the exception
var validPerson = new Person(1, "12345678");
var invalidPerson = new Person(1, "123456789");
var invalidPerson2 = new Person(1, "1234567");


It should be != instead of ==, but good answer!

I appreciate your answers a lot but I don't see how can I use this approach for my specific problem. In fact, I'm already reading a big unformatted file with many records, using FORTRAN, where I can easily control the format of my customized record, including integers, floats, fixed-length strings. Now, I want to translate my FORTRAN code to C#. Thus, I need to define a record or struct  with the exact format of the records of my file. In the solution you kindly propose, I would have to check the length of the string at runtime. I can't see how to use your approach to my specific problem.

Fixed-length buffers can be defined as fields on an unsafe structs. This approach can help reduce the need for garbage collection when memory is sparse.
But they cannot be used as fields on record types (not even record struct), and they cannot be used as parameters to methods or constructors, as you appear to be trying to do. You would need to take another type (a string or a Span<char> or maybe a char*) as an argument, and perform any length validation at run-time.
unsafe
{
    Person foo = new Person(25, "01011995");

    Console.Write("Birthdate: ");
    char* bd = foo.birthdate;
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(bd[i]);
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}


public unsafe struct Person 
{
    public int age;
    public fixed char birthdate[8];

    public Person(int age, ReadOnlySpan<char> date)
    {
        if (date.Length != 8)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Date must be exactly 8 characters long.");
        }

        this.age = age;
        fixed (char* b = birthdate)
        fixed (char* d = date)
        {
            Buffer.MemoryCopy(d, b, 8 * sizeof(char), 8 * sizeof(char));
        }
    }
}


But I should point out that this is (as the keyword says) unsafe, and the vast majority of C# developers don't need to get this low-level. Most people are fine using things like strings and DateTimes.
